# Problem with Perl warnings and regex Use of uninitialized value in regexp compilation

Tags: regex, perl, warnings, initialization

I am calling the following script from my main Perl program.  The script takes a process name and returns its PID. 
The script is included in my main perl code by using the require key word:

```
require "getPid.pl";
```

and called using:

```
&pidGetter($processName);
```

getPid.pl is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Proc::ProcessTable;

pidGetter($ARGV[0]);

sub pidGetter
{
   my $ret="PROCESS ID NOT FOUND\n";
   my $t = new Proc::ProcessTable;
   my $procName = $_[0];

   foreach my $p (@{$t->table})
   {
      if ($p->fname =~ /$procName/)
      {
         $ret = $p->pid;
      }   
   }

   return $ret;
}
```

However, when the script is called, I get the following warning:

> Use of uninitialized value $procName in regexp compilation at getPid.pl line 19

The rest of the script seems to function fine.
It is my understanding that $procName is initialized by $procName = &_[0];

I have put in print statements to debug, and `$procName` does return a value, so it is initialised.  Does anyone know why I am getting these warnings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`require "getPid.pl";` evaluates the code contained in `getPid.pl`. So you actually call the `pidGetter()` function twice: in the `require`'d script and in the main script. As `$ARGV[0]` is `undef` inside the `require`'d script, you get the warning.